# multiplying number in a textbox to the quantity value

Tags: c#, numericupdown

I have this TextBox named Amount and a NumericUpDown named quantity1. How do i multiply the TextBox which is double to the value of the NumericUpdown?

```
double amt;
double ans;

amt = Double.Parse(Amount.Text);
tot = Double.Parse(Total.Text);

//I have another textbox called total.
ans = amt * (quantity1.Value) //how do i do this? it has error.
```

Comment: You got your answer but when you say there's an error, It would help others answer your question quickly if you add the error text in your question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double amt = Convert.ToDouble(Amount.Text);
double qnt = Convert.ToDouble(quantity.Value);
double ans = amt * qnt;
Total.Text = ans.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

convert the value of quantity1.Value to double AND after apply multiplication and then convert the result to string and assign to textbox it may resolve your problem